# ImageView black background on some devices

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I have a ListView that contains images (each row), the width of each image is match_parent and the height is about 0.4 of the width.

Now everything works fine, except on big screen devices (like nexus 7...), instead of the images I see black background

Here is my ListView adapter

```
public class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    int width = 0;

    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] title;
    private final int[] img;

    public PlansAdapter(Activity context,
                        String[] title, int[] img) {
        super(context, R.layout.listsingle, title);
        this.context = context;
        this.title = title;
        this.img = img;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listsingle, null, true);
        TextView Title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        Title.setText(title[position]);
        ImageView Img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        Img.setImageResource(img[position]);
        width = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        double a = (double) 44/96;

        Img.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (a*width);

        RelativeLayout bghover = (RelativeLayout )convertView.findViewById(R.id.bghover);
        bghover.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (a*width);


        return convertView;
    }
}
```

In the next activity I use the same code and I see the image.

```
width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
double a = (double) 44/96;
Img.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (a*width);
```

I think the device memory isn't big enough to show all the images

Here is the logcat

> eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
>
> Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN,
>   keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100,
>   metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=497,
>   eventTime=242910, downTime=216396, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
>
> Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN,
>   keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100,
>   metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=498,
>   eventTime=242960, downTime=216396, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
>
> GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1461K, 8% free 18275K/19844K, paused 6ms, total 6ms

Comment: Try change this line `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listsingle, null, true);` to `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listsingle, parent, false);`

Comment: @AnggrayudiH same thing, still black background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the device runs out of memory or something like this.
I've made the photos to load in background and now everything works fine.